# Retrieving object children while using Transformers.aliasToBean

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I've got a question regarding children retrieval when using Transformers.aliasToBean function in Hibernate. I've wrote a query which populates my object, but when I try to populate children query doesn't work. I'll post sample code first and add generated SQL and exception below.

Parent

```
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="parent_id")
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private List<Child> children;

    @Transient
    private long someCount;

    // public constructor + getters and setters

}
```

Child

```
public class Child {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    // public constructor + getters and setters
}
```

Query

```
Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT p.id as id, p.name as name, "
    + " (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM stat WHERE parent_id=p.id) as someCount, "
    + " FROM " + Parent.class.getSimpleName() + " p ")                     
.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Parent.class));
```

Basically when I try to include `p.children as children` right in the first line of query I get the following sql generated by hibernate:

```
select parent0_.id as col_0_0_, parent0_.name as col_1_0_, . as col_2_0_, 
(select count(*) from stats stat3_ where parent_id=parent0_.id) as col_3_0_, child2_.id 
as id1_2_1_ from inner join child child2_ on parent0_.id=child2_.parent_id
```

And the error is:

```
WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42601
ERROR: ERROR: syntax error at or near "." at position 60
```

That position 60 corresponds to `, . as col_2_0_,` the position before the dot in the first line of the query. Basically it seems to retrieve the children, but generated SQL prevents it from successfully executing the query.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply speaking, you can not add `p.children` to result columns of `SELECT`, because it's a collection, and only entities or scalars are allowed here. But you can try this alternative:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT p, "
    + " (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM stat WHERE parent_id=p.id) "
    + " FROM " + Parent.class.getSimpleName() + " p " +
    + " LEFT JOIN FETCH p.children ");
for (Object[] row : (List<Object[]>)query.list()) {
    Parent p = (Parent)row[0];
    p.setSomeCount(((Number)row[1]).longValue());
}
```

Please tell if it really works for you.

Comment: I have used very similar approach to solve my problem. Could not find how to do it with Transformers.aliasToBean method. Since the questions has the only answer and you are close to my solution I will accept your answer and award you with rep ;)